# Changing existing files with Yeoman

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I would like to prompt the user with the question "What would you like to name your component? And subsequently go through a directory of file recursively and change all instances of _MY_COMPONENT_NAME_ with the users input.

How would I go about accomplishing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`fs.copyTpl`](https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor#copytplfrom-to-context-options). This is one of the Yeoman [file helpers](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html).

So inside your generator `writing` phase, you'd write something like:

```
writing: function () {
  this.fs.copyTpl(
    this.templatePath('**'),
    this.destinationPath(),
    { componentName: 'the component name' }
  )
}
```

Actual paths may vary depending on your project, but you get the idea: use glob to match a set of files.

And in your templates files, you'd just output the value with the template tag (here I use HTML, but this can be in any kind of file):

```
<h1>
  This is the <%= componentName %>
</h1>
```